# Flex wrap children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

Why is flex wrap not working here? I expect both children to wrap together, but each child only wraps on its own.

```css
.hap-playlist {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 300px;
}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap div {
  display: inline-block;

}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap {
  display: flex-inline;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;

}
```

```html
<div class="hap-playlist">

  <div class="hap-playlist-title-wrap">
  
    <div class="hap-playlist-title">Orinoco Flow</div><div class="hap-playlist-artist">Enya Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna.
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

I am looking it to wrap as it was a single div.

Comment: Did you mean to have `display: inline-flex;` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly, I think you are looking for something like this,

It all depends on the width and the amount of flex each child takes in.

```css
.hap-playlist {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 500px;
}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap div {
  display: inline-block;

}
.hap-playlist-artist {
  flex:3;
}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="hap-playlist">

  <div class="hap-playlist-title-wrap">
  
    <div class="hap-playlist-title">Orinoco Flow</div><div class="hap-playlist-artist">Enya Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna.
    </div>
     <div class="hap-playlist-title">Orinoco Flow</div>
 <div class="hap-playlist-title">Orinoco Flow</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is flex wrap not working here?

It is working correctly :)

For exemple if your parent div do `100px` and you children are `90px` and `30px``

It means the second child with `30px` will be under the child with `90px`.  It won't be possible for these to be outside the parent with `100px`

Here is an exemple if you change the width of your element

```css
.hap-playlist {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap div {
  display: inline-flex;

}

.hap-playlist-title-wrap {
  display: flex-inline;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.hap-playlist-artist {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hap-playlist">

  <div class="hap-playlist-title-wrap">
  
    <div class="hap-playlist-title">Orinoco Flow</div><div class="hap-playlist-artist">Enya Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in neque. Vivamus tellus. Donec magna.
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want it to wrap as all was a single span, without any widths defined.